# using bs4 get garbled code when find values inside tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
def getAllBooksPagesURLs():
    lists_of_url = []
    lists_of_url.append(r"http://books.toscrape.com/")
    for j in range(2,51):
        lists_of_url.append(r"http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-%d.html"%j)
    return lists_of_url

def getAndParseURL(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def getBooksURLs(url,z):
    soup = getAndParseURL(url)
    return([z+ x.a.get('href') for x in soup.findAll( "div", class_="image_container")])

books_url = []
title_list = []
main_page_list = []
list_of_rewiew_num = []
list_of_bookpage = []
list_of_resultitle = []
books_done_page = []
list_of_review_num=[]

for y in getAllBooksPagesURLs()[0:1]:
    main_page=getAndParseURL(y)
    result_of_title = main_page.findAll("h3")
    for x in  result_of_title:
        list_of_resultitle.append(x.find("a").get("title"))
        books_url = getBooksURLs(y,y)

        for b in books_url:
    
             print(b)
             books_page = getAndParseURL(b)
             if books_page.find("td") is None:
                 list_of_review_num.append(0)
             else:
                 review_num =books_page.find("td").contents[0]

                 list_of_review_num.append(review_num)
books_url
list_of_resultitle
list_of_review_num
```

> above is my code ,the result is

['a897fe39b1053632',
'90fa61229261140a',
'6957f44c3847a760',
'e00eb4fd7b871a48',
'4165285e1663650f',
'f77dbf2323deb740',
'2597b5a345f45e1b',
'e72a5dfc7e9267b2',
'e10e1e165dc8be4a',
'1dfe412b8ac00530',
'0312262ecafa5a40',
'30a7f60cd76ca58c',
'ce6396b0f23f6ecc',
'3b1c02bac2a429e6',
'a34ba96d4081e6a4',
'deda3e61b9514b83',
'feb7cc7701ecf901',
'e30f54cea9b38190',
'a18a4f574854aced',
'a22124811bfa8350']

> the garble codes are like 'a22124811bfa8350', is it about dynamic html? I donnot know.
> my desire output of list_of_review_num should be

```
[0,1,2,3]
```

how to get the correct output?could you plz help me? thank u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code is outputting the result that you have is that you are using `.find()` which will find the first occurrence of the `td` tag, since there are numerous tags on the page you are working with and that the reviews would be the last `td` tag you should do something like this.

```
if books_page.find("td") is None: # saying that there is no td tags at all
    list_of_review_num.append(0)
else:
    review_num = books_page.find_all("td")[-1].contents[0] # using find_all and accessing the last td tag element 

    list_of_review_num.append(review_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue here, you select upc information and not the reviews. I recommend to avoid all these lists to store your results, better use dicts instead:

```
data = []

for y in getAllBooksPagesURLs()[0:1]:
    main_page=getAndParseURL(y)
    books_url = getBooksURLs(y,y)

    for b in books_url:
        books_page = getAndParseURL(b)
        d = {
            'title': books_page.h1.text,
            'url':b
        }
        d.update(dict(x.stripped_strings for x in books_page.select('table tr')))
        data.append(d)
data
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getAllBooksPagesURLs():
    lists_of_url = []
    lists_of_url.append(r"http://books.toscrape.com/")
    for j in range(2,51):
        lists_of_url.append(r"http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-%d.html"%j)
    return lists_of_url

def getAndParseURL(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def getBooksURLs(url,z):
    soup = getAndParseURL(url)
    return([z+ x.a.get('href') for x in soup.find_all( "div", class_="image_container")])

data = []

for y in getAllBooksPagesURLs()[0:1]:
    books_url = getBooksURLs(y,y)

    for b in books_url:
        books_page = getAndParseURL(b)
        d = {
            'title': books_page.h1.text,
            'url':b
        }
        d.update(dict(x.stripped_strings for x in books_page.select('table tr')))
        data.append(d)
data
```

##### Output:

```
[{'title': 'A Light in the Attic',
  'url': 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/a-light-in-the-attic_1000/index.html',
  'UPC': 'a897fe39b1053632',
  'Product Type': 'Books',
  'Price (excl. tax)': '£51.77',
  'Price (incl. tax)': '£51.77',
  'Tax': '£0.00',
  'Availability': 'In stock (22 available)',
  'Number of reviews': '0'},
 {'title': 'Tipping the Velvet',
  'url': 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/tipping-the-velvet_999/index.html',
  'UPC': '90fa61229261140a',
  'Product Type': 'Books',
  'Price (excl. tax)': '£53.74',
  'Price (incl. tax)': '£53.74',
  'Tax': '£0.00',
  'Availability': 'In stock (20 available)',
  'Number of reviews': '0'},...]
```

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*